# Reading input text through scrolled window?

Tags: pygtk

I have created a scrolled window using pyGTK. When I type some text in the scrolled window,that typed text must be written in a file. I have a function which could write to the file. But as and when I go typing some text into the scrolled window that function must be called. If anyone suggest me the solution that would be very helpufull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import glib, gtk

saveFilePath = 'textview.txt'

isChanged = True

def onBufferChanged(b):
    global isChanged
    isChanged = True

def onTimeout():
    if isChanged:
        text = textbuff.get_text(textbuff.get_start_iter(), textbuff.get_end_iter())
        open(saveFilePath, 'w').write(text)
        isChanged = False
    return True ## Continue loop

textview = gtk.TextView()
textbuff = textview.get_buffer()
textbuff.connect('changed', onBufferChanged)
glib.timeout_add_seconds(1, onTimeout)

dialog = gtk.Dialog()
dialog.vbox.pack_start(textview, 1, 1)
dialog.vbox.show_all()
dialog.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to change event of text area were you type text and then schedule and execution of function that saves the text to file say each 1 second, so as you type your text would automatically saved. or you could have a background thread that monitors state of that control and save-s it regularly with 1 second delay so that. I think thread way is more correct

Comment: I don't think the thread way is the easiest. The easiest way is to call the writing function at regular intervals with `glib.timeout_add_seconds()`.

Comment: yup but that would give you a lots of subsequent writes for each character the user types, thus you must filter conditions when to write and when to not to write, but the thus it's better to have a seperate thread for writing process with 1 second delayed execution which will change if there is a need to write anything

Comment: then you should set e `is_changed` flag to True on `GtkTextBuffer`s `changed` handler. and check for this flag in `timeout_add_seconds` s handler, if it was True, write to file and set it to False, otherwise do nothing.